# I need to run more than one session in php ... is it possible

Tags: php

Can you  have more that one session running at the same time in php?

Most likely a dumb question... But I have never had to use more than a single session in my programming but now I am in need to do so.

Comment: You can assign different session names and variables, if that's what you're wondering.

Comment: 1 session can hold any amount of values ? why do you want multiple session in the 1st place ?

Comment: It's unclear whether you mean "more than one session for a single user", in which case @AkhilSidharth's comment is relevant, or "multiple sessions for multiple users", which is the default for web applications.

Comment: You should elaborate more. I can't think of _one_ use case where this would fit.

Comment: As others have stated, you *should* only really need one session. If you have a good reason why you think you need more than 1, then please say. Otherwise I suggest you need to rethink your design approach for whatever you think you need separate sessions for.

Comment: I am adding onsite analytics to my site to track page views and such of a user identified as a contact. I am wanting to assign them to a contact session which feeds the contact_session mysql table with a variety of variables. Should the user login that would start their logged in session but I would like the first session to continue running

Comment: A cookie is set to identify the contact when they arrive... should I close the session if they login and track their activity from there?

Comment: You can use the `session_name()` function before `session_start()` to switch between different named sessions.

Comment: But I suggest you just use different variables. Have a single session, and a variable like `$_SESSION['logged_in']` to indicate whether they're logged in or not.

Comment: You can assign a session variable to the user that logs in or tracked in your DB by doing `$id=$_SESSION['userid'];` then use that variable in your DB using a WHERE clause, which will track the user's ID while using the same session. For example: `WHERE userid='$id'`

Comment: After reading your appreciated comments i realized how to accomplish what is needed without running two sessions... but it is good to know it can be done... thanks for your time to all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have as much as you want, I doubt it's really useful but here is how to do it :

To create a new session with an array :

```
$session1 = array();
$session1['foo'] = 'bar';

file_put_contents(session_id().'/'.time(), serialize($session1));
```

To get all sessions for one user :

```
$sessions = array[];

foreach(scandir(session_id()) as $path){
    if(is_file(session_id().'/'.$path)){
        $sessions[] = unserialize(file_get_contents(session_id().'/'.$path));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Loric for your input. After reading the comments here I too have com to the realization that two sessions running at the same time is not necessary... I gave you the check because your provided the solution to accomplish the task... thanks for your time.

Answer (score -3):

I think u can't do that because "A visitor accessing your web site is assigned a unique id, the so-called session id. This is either stored in a cookie on the user side or is propagated in the URL.

The session support allows you to store data between requests in the $_SESSION superglobal array"

[Introduction to PHP Session Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php)

Comment: *"Warning

This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0 and REMOVED as of PHP 5.4.0."* --- This should've been a comment.

Comment: This function has nothing to do with multiple sessions. It merely turns ordinary variables into session variables.